# Ao carregar página, abrir primeira aba com resultados

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Tenho cinco abas, e cada uma exibe ou não o resultado de uma consulta no banco.

```
<div class="container">  
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <a data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link" href="#basic">Basic</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link" href="#gold">Gold></a>
    </li>
     .
     .
     .
</ul>
```

a aba basic é ativada quando carrega a pagina:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[href="#basic"]').tab('show');
    });
</script>
```

Ocorre que como cada aba é o resultado de uma consulta, pode ocorrer de a aba "basic" não conter dados nenhum para exibir, e as demais sim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Procuro uma solução para exibir a primeira aba com resultado,  ao carregar a pagina

NOTA: Utilizo ListView para exibir os dados.

Comment: Qual o HTML da aba?

Comment: <div class="tab-content">
     <div id="basic" class="tab-pane fade in active">

Comment: Tenta isso: `$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.tab-pane').each(function(){
      if($(this).children().length){
         $('a[href="#'+ this.id +'"]').tab('show');
         return false;
      }
   });
});`

Comment: @Sam abriu a aba "basic", que é a primeira. No teste, essa aba não poderia abrir, pois não continha dados da consulta, e as outras sim. Retornou apenas a mensagem de retorno do <EmptyDataTemplate> do ListView.

Comment: Será que verificando se contém algum texto na aba funciona?

Comment: eu tenho essas variáveis na pagina que mostram se a aba tem ou não dados: <% Response.Write(Basic);%> e assim sucessivamente para cada uma das cinco abas. Acho que essas variáveis podem ajudar a resolver o problema.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90348/discussion-between-sam-and-daniel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme conversado no chat, basta procurar nas guias das abas o primeiro valor diferente de `0` na tag `<sup>`:

```
<li class="active"> 
   <a data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link" href="#basic">
      Basic <sup><% Response.Write(Basic);%></sup>
   </a> 
</li>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a[data-toggle=tab]').each(function(){
      if(Number($("sup", this).text())){
         $(this).tab('show');
         return false;
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: se todos forem "0" tem que abrir uma delas para mostrar a mensagem do ListView que não há dados nessa visão e etc. Faltou esse detalhe apenas.

Comment: Ah sim... vou ver aqui

Comment: Dá uma olhada no código: https://jsfiddle.net/kyq5dcao/

Comment: Perfect. Exatamente o comportamento esperado. Muito obrigado.